# SQL Query - Return rows where based on dual conditioning of same column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am struggling to figure this out. I have a column, "Column1" that is VARCHAR(max) and contains a lot of raw text. I want to filter out rows based on this column not having a particular word in the column UNLESS a secondary condition is met.

For example:

Return all rows where the word "Final" does not exist. However, if the word "Final" does not exist but the word "Ongoing" does exist, then I need to return this row and not hide it.

Here is my code (not working)

```
SELECT *
FROM ThisTable
WHERE (
        Column1 NOT LIKE '%Final%'
        OR Column1 LIKE '%Ongoing%'
        )
```

Here are some examples of data that exists, and whether the row should be returned.

```
Row 1: "this project has ended" (return this row)
Row 2: "this project has ended but is ongoing" (return this row)
Row 3: "this project is final." (do not return this row)
Row 4: "This project is final and ongoing" (return this row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query is filtering out records where neither 'final' nor ongoing are contained, but as I understand it you want to return everything apart from records that include 'final' but don't also contain 'ongoing'.
I think something like this should work:

```
WHERE NOT (Column1 LIKE '%Final%' AND Column1 NOT LIKE '%Ongoing%')
```

Comment: This was my original query. It does not work correctly because it is only looking for rows that do not contain final but do contain ongoing. There will be rows where there is no final and no ongoing.

Comment: Those should be returned by this query - the NOT means it only excludes where both conditions are met.

Comment: This works. You were right about the "AND" Kudos